# SQL group by missing expression

Tags: sql, database, group-by, oracle10g

Assume i have two table (attributes are in parentheses).

1. **products** (pid, releasedate, productname, price, description)
2. **sells** (sellid, sellproductid, selluserid, selldate, selltype)

From this the output will result to this problem: **"Show all products with each total sell"**
I wrote this SQL query with no luck:

```
select pid, productname, price, count(pid) from products p, sells s having p.pid = s.sellproductid group by pid;
```

Sound like the group by is not working, with sql minor knowledge i can't understand how to fix this...any idea?

Comment: sure.. i am editing my Q in a second..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include all the non-aggregated fields in the group by expression. Try This:

```
select pid, productname, price, count(1) as ProductsSold,count(1)*price as Income
from products p, sells s 
where p.pid = s.sellproductid 
group by pid, productname, price
```

Comment: Thankyou, it worked like a charm! can i add something if you dont mind, how i can multiply with total sell with each product price and put them in a new column? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select pid, producname,price from products p inner join sells s on p.pid=s.sellproductid group by pid.
```

becouse function count() returned one row.

Comment: ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression

Cause: The GROUP BY clause does not contain all the expressions in the SELECT clause. SELECT expressions that are not included in a group function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, must be listed in the GROUP BY clause.

source: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm